# telescope install fails on laravel-7.25

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, telescope

**PHP 7.4.3**

**Laravel Version: 7.24**

I just tried to composer require laravel/telescope and composer install failed.

```
Using version ^4.0 for laravel/telescope
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/telescope ^4.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/telescope[4.x-dev, v4.0.0].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[v7.28.1, 8.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v7.28.1].
    - Can only install one of: laravel/framework[8.x-dev, v7.28.1].
    - Conclusion: install laravel/framework 8.x-dev
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.28.1, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.2",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "intervention/image": "^2.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.24",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
        "laravel/ui": "^2.1"
    },
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Why not use a version of `laravel/telescope` that is compatible with your version of `laravel/framework`?

Answer (score 8):

```
composer require laravel/telescope "^3.0"
```

should bring it to work.
p.s. I am using Laravel 7 for most of projects I worked on and had to try different combinations between Laravel 7 and telescope package. `telescope ^3.0` seems to be the latest compatible version with Laravel 7.

Comment: please provide more info why and how your response resolve the problem.

Comment: This version of telescope worked for me. Laravel Framework version 7.29.3

Comment: Thanks for following up @Dmytro I simply chose the latest compatible version of telescope on the basis that the topic is discussing about Laravel 7.2*

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same issue.

```
composer require laravel/telescope "^2.0"
```

was successful

```
- Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v7.28.1, required as ^7.24) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v7.28.1].
```

Tells you what is going on. The project you are working on is locked to laravel/framework v7.28.1. The current version of Telescope requires laravel/framework ^8.0. Maybe you will be able to use telescope v3.0.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me

```
composer require laravel/telescope:3
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me solve the same problem

```
composer require laravel/framework -W
```

and

```
composer require laravel/telescope
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`composer require laravel/telescope`

it updated my telescope to `laravel/telescope": "^4.9`

then i ran `composer update -w`

and i was good to go.

oh, i need to mention that the project is in `laravel/framework": "^7.24|^8.0`  but i added the ^8.0 and did the same for `php": "^7.2.5|^8.0`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
composer require laravel/telescope "^1.2"  or
composer require laravel/telescope "^2.0"

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. As far as I see, v1.2 of `laravel/telescope` is not compatible with Laravel v7.